# Very odd event behaviour for onChange on Telerik MVC DatePicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik, telerik-mvc

To the question started, my code (I'll try to only include relevant portions to start), starting with my script:

```
function RaceDate_onChange() {
    var pickedDate = $(this).data('tDatePicker').value();
    var month = pickedDate.getMonth() + 1;
    $.get("/RaceCard/Details?year=" + pickedDate.getFullYear() + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + pickedDate.getDate());
}
```

Then my markup:

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.RaceDate).ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("RaceDate_onChange"))
```

And finally a bit of the receiving action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int year, int month, int day)
{
    var viewModel = new RaceCardModel {Metadata = DetailModelMetadata.Display, RaceDate = new DateTime(year, month, day)};
```

I'm trying to get the selection of a new date to trigger a GET, to refresh the page without submitting a form.  This works fine, except for *this* problem:

In GET requests to the `Details` action, the `day` value is always one day behind the DatePicker.  E.g. The first value is set from a view model property, when the view is rendered, say 3.  I then click on 14 and hit my breakpoint in the action method.  The `day` value is 3.  When I click on 29 and hit the breakpoint, the `day` value is 14.

Besides asking what is wrong, I'll take a liberty and ask if there is a better way that is no more complicated.  I am fairly novice and would rather deliver working code that needs revision than get bogged down in tangents and details.

Comment: What happens when you alert the current date before sending it? Try this: alert(pickedDate); alert(pickedDate.getDate());

Comment: @Atanas, I start on July 11, then click on July 13.  Both alerts give me 11.  Maybe something to log with Telerik?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using e.value instead as shown in the [client-side events](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/clientsideevents) example. You are probably using an older version where the value() method returned the previous value during the OnChange event.

UPDATE:

"e.value" means the value field of the OnChange arguments:

```
function onChange(e) {
   var date = e.value; // instead of datePicker.value()
}
```

Comment: I see no Razor example using lambda syntax, and I cannot get it working.  Could you assist here please?

Comment: Why do you need example with razor syntax - the code is exactly the same. Simply use the value field of the event argument. function(e) { var value = e.value; }

Comment: I only asked for assistance after trying several times to get the lamba syntax working, and only managing to get the simple, function name argument for events working.

Comment: So did you try my suggestion or not? To get the value from the event argument of the OnChange event?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the 1 month difference you are getting, that's normal, and it is how the [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method works in javascript on a `Date` instance:

> The value returned by getMonth is an
>   integer between 0 and 11. 0
>   corresponds to January, 1 to February,
>   and so on.

So adding +1 is the correct way to cope with the situation, exactly as you did.

Just a little remark about your AJAX call: never hardcode urls. Always use url helpers when dealing with urls:

```
var year = pickedDate.getFullYear();
var month = pickedDate.getMonth() + 1;
var day = pickedDate.getDate();
var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "RaceCard")';
$.get(url, { year: year, month: month, day: day }, function(result) {
    // process the results of the AJAX call
});
```

Comment: The x = 1/0 was an oopsie I left behind while trying to get the JS debugger in Chrome to halt.  But, you do misunderstand me about the day.  The value I'm getting is not just 1 less than when I expect.

When the even fires, it passes me the day value that was on the picker before the new day value is selected.  I have tried to make that clear in the example, and even clearer now I have eliminated any chance of my example illustrating a simple off-by-one issue.

Comment: @ProfK, you probably are not calling this `RaceDate_onChange` method at the right time. It looks like it is called before the actual value changes. As you haven't shown how and where you have registered this `RaceDate_onChange` method I don't see how I could help you further.

Comment: My code is copy pasted from the Telerik docs for "Subscribing to the OnChange event", except for a name change for the control.  I am trying to create condensed example code .

Comment: Sorry, I did paste the wrong clipboard into my markup example.  It's fixed now.